# Change in PHP code of password from MD5 to WordPress password encryption

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

How can I modify my code to change my password from MD5 to WordPress password like $P$B? Because my app user register info send to wp-users. And now I cannot login into my app with the information registered by user in Woocommerce site in Wordpress. I find because of password.

I know if I want connect the password with my app, I just need reset the password to MD5 in localhost, but because I don't know my user password, so I cannot use this method, so I plan to do the user register their account in my app and the password send to wp-users will become same as WordPress. My password encryption key word in PHP code is this line:

```
$user_pass = md5($user_pass);
```

Below is my code:

```
<?php 

class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($user_login, $user_pass,$user_email){
        if($this->isUserExist($user_login,$user_email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $user_pass = md5($user_pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`,`user_email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$user_login,$user_pass,$user_email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($user_login, $user_pass){
        $user_pass = md5($user_pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ? AND user_pass = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user_login,$user_pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($user_login){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_login);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($user_login, $user_email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = ? OR user_email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_login, $user_email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: if got other answer, please comment in here, still not find solution now

Answer (score 0):

**Create Password:**

```
$plain_password="string";

$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(16, true);   
$password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword($plain_password);
```

`$password` is now similar to the password stored in wordpress database.

**Check password:**

```
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(16, true);
if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $user_pass)) {
            //statement
} else {
           //statement
}
```

> You need to include `PasswordHash` class. Available here:
>   https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-phpass.php

Comment: this code just only replace the line         $user_pass = md5($user_pass);
?

Comment: May I know create password and check password code write at where?